# Need help with notation used in McCallum-Relyea key exchange explanation

Tags: group-theory, cryptography

I want to better understand the McCallum-Relyea (MR) key exchange used in software called Clevis and Tang. (I'm an IT person, please excuse me for being mathematically not very precise.)

It is related to the Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange that I understand in its simplest form using the function (A**B mod P) with fixed prime P. I know that other operation may be used if it satisfy certain conditions.

The document I found uses a "multiplicative notation" (google find that for me). Link is: https://people.redhat.com/pladd/NYRHUG_NBDE_2020-02.pdf pages 23 and 25.

The DH key exchange is written there using `AB` instead of e.g. `(A**B mod P)`.

1. Alice chooses secret `C` and sends `c=gC` to Bob.
2. Bob chooses secret `S` and sends `s=gS` to Alice.
3. Alice computes `K=sC=gSC`; Bob computes `K=cS=gCS`

Keeping in mind that `gX` is a notation for `(g**X) mod P` I can follow that and I see why `gSC == gCS`. So far so good.

However the MR description introduces addition and substraction and computes for instance:

```
x = c + e
y = xS
```

and the explanation in the document makes sense to me only if `y = cS + eS`. My question is what that plus operation (and also the minus elsehwere in the document) are in reality. It canot be the regular addition, because `(c+e)**S mod P != c**S mod P + e**S mod P).`

---

UPDATE: with the help of @R_Marche and after studying the slide #31 in this [presentation](https://www.snia.org/sites/default/files/SDC15_presentations/security/NathanielMcCallum_Network_Bound_Encryption.pdf) I could wrote a quick&dirty program in Python that does the computation step by step and comes to the correct answer. That answers the question to me. I'm a guest here, don't know if it is OK, but I'm attaching the program.

```
import random

class ModGrp:
    def __init__(self, g, p): 
        self.gen = g 
        self.p = p 
    def rnd(self):
        return random.randrange(1, self.p)
    def add(self, a, b):
        return (a*b) % self.p
    def sub(self, a, b):
        return self.add(a, self.inv(b))
    def mul(self, a, b):
        return pow(a, b, self.p)
    def inv(self, x):
        return pow(x, self.p-2, self.p)

mg = ModGrp(17,443)

# -- provisioning --
# on server
SS = mg.rnd()
s = mg.mul(mg.gen, SS)
# on client
CC = mg.rnd()
c = mg.mul(mg.gen, CC)
K1 = mg.mul(s, CC) 
del CC

# -- recovery --
# on client
EE = mg.rnd()
e = mg.mul(mg.gen, EE) 
x = mg.add(c, e)
# on server
y = mg.mul(x, SS) 
# back on client
K2 = mg.sub(y, mg.mul(s, EE))

print(f"created={K1} recovered={K2}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Diffie-Helmann key exchange (and in algorithms derived from it) you are dealing with a *group*.
A group $G$ consists of a set of elements and of an operation that combines them.

Your doubts are probably caused by the fact that there are two main ways to denote the group operation: one *additive* and one *multiplicative*.

Assume $x,y$ are elements in $G$, and that the operation in $G$ is $ \circ$.

In the additive notation you'd write $x + y$ instead of  $x \circ y $, and $n\cdot x$ instead of repeating $x\circ x \circ  \cdots \circ x$ for $n$ times.

In the multiplicative notation (which seems to be the one you're more used to), you instead write
$x\cdot y$ instead of  $x \circ y$ and $x^n$ instead of repeating $x\circ x \circ  \cdots \circ x$ for $n$ times.

Now, to answer you actual question. In the notation used by the slides the set you are working with is the set $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the integers modulo $p$. The operation $\circ$  is the modular addition, so it is denoted in *additive* notation, with a + . It follows that the repeated addition is denoted by a multiplication $n\cdot x$.
The reason you may find this confusing is that when you learned the DH algorithm, you saw it written with the multiplicative notation. I suggest you to try and rewrite the DH algorithm you already know by swapping all $\cdot$ with $+$ and all exponentiations with multiplications. The same thing seen from two different perspective might help you to make the "jump" to the new version of the key exchange.

Comment: It helped me to advance in the right direction. Thank you, accepted. (and I added an UPDATE to the question)